# Node-sass на arm (m1)

Tags: node-sass, m1

Как поднять docker на m1? Начинает поднимать проект, потом пишет ошибку (на картинке). Я ушла на винду, но это еще хуже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Docker очевидно ни при чём и нормально работает, проблема в Node Sass

Comment: Мне сказали следующее: пакет node-sass пока что не поддерживает чипы на архитектуре arm. Как это можно обойти или исправить? Совсем пока нет вариантов?

Comment: Никак. Вообще-то  node-sass считается устаревшим и все переходят на dart-sass. Но кажется он тоже ещё не умеет m1.